# question about jQuery inline form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Here is a link on   jQuery inline form validation that I'm trying to use
http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/

Everything looks good but I have a small problem

I have an input where I use this kind of validation

```
'validate[length[6,15]]'
```

It checks if number of length of input value and if it is less then 6 or grater then 15 gives and error.

Now what I want is to add there chance for input to have value length=0 , so the validation won't fire any error message.

Is that possible ?

**UPDATE**

This is submit blocking function

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function() {
$('#standart_form').validationEngine();
 $('#standart_form').submit(function() {
  return false;
 });
 });
  </script>
```

Now when I was using this `'validate[length[6,15]]'` everything was working good. But If I try using new custom functions the whole forms submits itself ruining my ajax based application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin you're using doesn't support this out of the box, but its customization features allows you to implement that behavior yourself.

For instance, you can specify a regular expression to be used when validating a field. You'll need to add it to your translation file:

```
"emptyOrLengthBetween6And15": {
    "regex": /^$|^.{6,15}$/,
    "alertText": "* Empty, or between 6 and 15 characters long"
},
```

Then you can refer to it in a `custom` validator:

```
class="validate[custom[emptyOrLengthBetween6And15]]"
```

You can also write your own validation function:

```
function checkEmptyOrLengthBetween6And15(field, rules, i, options)
{
    var val = field.val();
    if (val.length > 0 && (val.length < 6 || val.length > 15)) {
        return "* Empty, or between 6 and 15 characters long";
    }
}
```

Then use it in a `funcCall` validator:

```
class="validate[funcCall[checkEmptyOrLengthBetween6And15]]"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try to make custom regular expression

Comment: one more question, I use this in form which is called by ajax and is submitted by ajax. I also have javascript function which prevents php to php submit the form when submit button is pressed. And when I use standard validation functions all works. But When I use your custom, it works but also submits the form via php. Do you know how to prevent custom functions from auto submit ?

Comment: @David, sorry, my bad, the function should return an error message, not a boolean value. Answer updated accordingly.

Comment: it submits the whole form when I press submit :( If I use default functions then form is not submitted so my ajax works fine. That's the problem :(

Comment: @David, according to the plugin's documentation, there should not be any difference. Can you update your question with more of your code, especially the function you're using to prevent form submission?

Comment: Strange, it should work without the blocking function. Are you also calling `validationEngine()` on the form after it's been loaded through AJAX?

Comment: this function which you see comes with html of the form and is loaded into ajax application simultaniously with the form itself. Other then this function I do not call validationEngine() from any other place.

Comment: Strange is that default functions work fine, but all custom auto submit the form after I press submit button